# Creating a vuejs audio player

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, html5-audio, quasar-framework

I am working on a audio player in vuejs but I am struggling with how to get the quasar slider component to keep ticking with time as the music plays and how to stop it if the user clicks the pause button. I thought a promise would work best but I think I may be wrong about that! The browser screen usually starts to lag because of my current code. I also am not able to click the button again to pause it because maybe the code is still running from the promise?

```
<template>
  <div style="min-height: 667px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <div class="bg-white flex flex-center" style="min-height: 40vh">
      <div class="absolute" style="width: 100%; max-width: 500px">
        <h3 class="text-center text-h4 text-primary text-weight-bold">
          WITHOUT VOCALS
        </h3>
        <div class="full-width flex flex-center">
          <q-btn
            flat
            round
            color="secondary"
            text-color="primary"
            icon="fa-solid fa-backward"
            class="q-ma-md"
            size="20px"
          />
          <q-btn
            flat
            round
            color="secondary"
            text-color="primary"
            :icon="vocalPlayIcon"
            size="30px"
            class="bg-secondary q-ma-md"
            @click="toggleAudioWithoutVocals()"
          />
          <q-btn
            flat
            round
            color="secondary"
            text-color="primary"
            icon="fa-solid fa-forward"
            class="q-ma-md"
            size="20px"
          />
          <audio
            style="display: none"
            id="audio-player-without-vocals"
            controls
          >
            <source src="~assets/audio/shinedown.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support the audio tag.
          </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="full-width" style="max-width: 800px">
          <q-slider
            v-model="vocalPlayTime"
            :min="0"
            :max="vocalAudioDuration"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const vocalPlayIcon = ref("fa-solid fa-play");
const vocalPlayTime = ref(0);
const vocalAudioDuration = ref(0);
const vocalAudioObj = ref(Object);

onMounted(() => {
  vocalAudioObj.value = document.getElementById("audio-player-without-vocals");
});

const toggleAudioWithoutVocals = () => {
  if (vocalAudioObj.value.paused) {
    playAudio().then((vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-play"));
  } else {
    vocalAudioObj.value.pause();
    vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-play";
  }
};

const playAudio = () => {
  vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-pause";
  vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.duration;
  vocalAudioObj.value.play();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    while (!vocalAudioObj.value.paused) {
      vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.curremtTime;
    }
    resolve();
  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Remove that `while` stuff (it's the reason why you got lags, because you have created an endless loop) and add an event listener to your `<audio>` element that listens for `timeupdate` events. Update the `vocalPlayTime.value` value within the event handler you attach to `timeupdate`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event).

Comment: Care to write up a response? I will also try to implment what you said. thanks

Comment: By the way, a little handy hint: if you add a `ref` attribute to `<audio> - like `<audio ref="vocalAudioObj" ....` you won't need the `onMounted` code

Comment: How do you access the ref in the js code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the first comment, you should remove the `while` loop as well as the `Promise` and instead listen for `timeupdate` events the `<audio>`-Element fires.

The `while` loop you've written results in an infinite loop that makes the browser lag.

```
onMounted(() => {
  vocalAudioObj.value = document.getElementById("audio-player-without-vocals");
  // add an event listener to the audio element
  vocalAudioObj.value.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.currentTime;
  });
});

const toggleAudioWithoutVocals = () => {
  if (vocalAudioObj.value.paused) {
    playAudio();
    // I think the next line of code is logically wrong, because
    // you don't want to show the play icon if audio plays already
    // that's why it is commented out
    // ---
    // vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-play"
  } else {
    vocalAudioObj.value.pause();
    vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-play";
  }
};

const playAudio = () => {
  vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-pause";
  // I'm not sure about the next line, because as soon as 
  // the audio plays, the vocalPlayTime.value is changed to 
  // the current playback time anyway
  // ---
  vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.duration;
  vocalAudioObj.value.play();
  // Removed the promise stuff
};
```

To make it look more consistent, I'd also restructure the code like this:

```
onMounted(() => {
  vocalAudioObj.value = document.getElementById("audio-player-without-vocals");
  vocalAudioObj.value.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.currentTime;
  });
});

const toggleAudioWithoutVocals = () => {
  if (vocalAudioObj.value.paused) {
    playAudio();
  } else {
    pauseAudio();
  }
};

const playAudio = () => {
  vocalPlayTime.value = vocalAudioObj.value.duration; // Still not sure about this...
  vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-pause";
  vocalAudioObj.value.play();
};

const pauseAudio = () => {
  vocalPlayIcon.value = "fa-solid fa-play";
  vocalAudioObj.value.pause();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this write up. Your code looks much cleaner than mine lol. I am going to try this out tonight. The line //still not sure about this. I did try this technique to see if the variable would keep updating but it only moved it once so its not like the event is binded too it and keeps updating. I was not sure how to exactly do that though and was thinking maybe I needed to try and use the computed property or something. Not sure.